# how to cut out a shape from an html element

Tags: html, css

I've been searching for 2 days now, reading up on clip, clip-path, masking and everything there is to know about this css-subject. 
But I can't figure out how to achieve the following:

I have a red body background color.
on top of this is a full-width, full height div, that's white. (red body isn't showing).
I want to cut out a shape out of the white div, to show a bit of red background.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Much appreciated!

Thanks

Mario.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ecaw94vw/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">


<!--<div class="svgMask" width="0" height="0">
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <mask id="svgmask2">
                <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="assets/images/masks/triangle-1-mask.svg"/>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <image mask="url(#svgmask2)" width="100%" height="100%" y="0" x="0" xlink:href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32494584/backdrop.jpg"/>
    </svg>
</div>-->

<div class="mask">

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The css

```
 body{
        background:red;
    }
    .mask{
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        background: white;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100px 100px, 200px 0px, 500px 500px);
    }
```

thanks

Comment: you can post your code or fiddle link.

Comment: Why would you need this?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I think I've found a solution here that suits your needs!

```css
.clip-text {
    font-size: 6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: .25em;
    padding: .5em .75em;
    text-align: center;
    /* Color fallback */
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;

    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.clip-text:before,
.clip-text:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
}


.clip-text:before {
    z-index: -2;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: inherit;
}


.clip-text:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: .125em;
    right: .125em;
    bottom: .125em;
    left: .125em;
    background-color: #000;
}


.clip-text--no-textzone:before {
    background-position: -.65em 0;
}

.clip-text--no-textzone:after {
    content: none;
}

.clip-text--cover,
.clip-text--cover:before {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}

.clip-text_one {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/7);
}
```

```html
<div class="clip-text clip-text_one">THIS IS CUT OUT</div>
```

Comment: Why do I get a down vote on this one, please explain :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it needs to be an actual "cut out". I need to see the background, because stuff will be happening on the background.
For example: if you background is a movie or image, It needs to be visible. Instead of creating a shape with the same background color.

Comment: I just edited my answer, and I think I've found something that you need :)