# how to cut shapes from a layover (or any other html element)

Tags: html, css

First of all I know that this question has been asked before (3 years ago) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784642/how-to-cut-out-a-shape-from-an-html-element), but I couldn't find a proper solution so I'm trying again.

I'm trying to implement the following design: 
[image: partial overlay]
I'm referring to this overlay which seems like it is missing a part.

My idea was setting a background image (first div), then cover it with this gradient-background overlay (second div), and then somehow subtracting from this overlay this rotated shape (third div).

being naive I thought that somehow I'll find a way to implement this subtraction operation, but here I'm after two days of trying.

I've read a lot about masking, but couldn't find a way of properly using it.

So my questions are:
This subtraction approach is the proper approach here? If it is, how can I achieve it? and If not? what other solution can you offer?

Thanks a lot!

Evyatar

Comment: I guess you are looking for blend mode rather than cutting a shape

Comment: you should share your code & what you tried once you searched and did not find a similar question . your question is a bad question as it is.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Exactly what I was missing. Thanks man.

Comment: @G-Cyr Thought the question was pretty clear. Had no code to share, just an idea in mind, which I didn't know how to implement. Anyway I'll try to give more details next time.

Answer (score 0):

example with mix-blend-mode before it get closed : *(answered for the fun to play with mix-blend-mode)*

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(165, 192, 253), rgb(247, 128, 132));
  padding: 2em;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 50px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 500px), url(https://www.bing.com/th?id=OIP.VYbZz4O-gR8sw8sRHAvh-gHaEK&pid=Api&rs=1 ) no-repeat white;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  position: relative;
}

body:after,
body:before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 15%;
  width: 75%;
  padding-top: 75%;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10%, -50%);
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  z-index: -1;
}

body:after {
  z-index: 1;
  background: #000
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.