# How can I get this blend mode effect on hero image and also fix the navigation menu opacity?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve this blend mode effect on hero image and transparent navbar with that disolve into the hero image. I tried to make transparent navbar by giving a background color and some opacity, but it doesnt look same as what I want.
[image]

What I have so far is this:
[image]

and here's the code for that:
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```css
.navbar {
  background: #000000 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  opacity: 0.56;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;

  @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;    
  }
 
    }

  &-collapse {
    justify-content: flex-end;

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      background: #402808 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
      .nav-item:last-child {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }

  &-nav {
    align-items: center;
  }

  .nav-item {
    margin-right: 4rem;
   
    transition: all 0.2s;
    &:hover {
      .nav-link {
        color: #f1cd9d !important;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
      margin-right: 3rem;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {  margin-right: 1rem; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      margin-right: 1rem;
    }
  }
}

.hero {
  background: url("/assets/src/images/hero.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
  .herowoman {
    left: 79.4rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35.3rem;
  }
  .row1 {
    margin-top: 18rem;
    justify-content: center;
    img {
      width: 251px;
      height: 192px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
      img {
        width: 155px;
        height: 118px;
      }
    }
  }

  .row2 {
    position: relative;
    h1 {
      &::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 2px;
        background: #efefef;
        width: 5.5%;
        @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
          width: 10.5%;
        }
      }
    }
    p {
      font-size: clamp(10rem, 24vw, 44rem);
      text-align: center;
      line-height: clamp(16rem, 22vw, 35rem);
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 6.16px;
      color: #ffffff;
      opacity: 0.26;
    }
    .herowoman {
      width: 371px;
      height: 543px;
      position: absolute;
      top: -2.5rem;
      left: 49.5rem;
    }

    button {
      z-index: 99;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0rem;
      top: 56rem;
      width: 214px;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        line-height: 6.5rem;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 11.3rem;
        line-height: 11.5rem;
      }
    }
  }
  .row3 {
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    img {
      width: 371px;
      height: 543px;
      position: absolute;
      top: -12rem;
      left: 49.5rem;
    }
    p {
      font: normal normal bold 440px/457px Poppins;
      letter-spacing: 6.16px;
      color: #ffffff;
      opacity: 0.26;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/html/index.php"><img src="/assets/src/images/logo.png" alt=""
                class="img-fluid"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler x" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link navmenu-text" aria-current="page" href="/html/index.php">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link navmenu-text" href="/html/about.php">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link navmenu-text" href="/html/services.php">services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link navmenu-text" href="/html/rooms.php">rooms</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link navmenu-text" href="/html/gallery.php">gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link navmenu-text" href="/html/contact.php">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <li class="nav-item-last">
                <a href="#" class=" d-flex">
                    <img src="../assets/src/images/location.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive">

                    <p class="nav-text">BHAIRAHAWA, RUPANDEHI</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class=" d-flex">
                    <img src="../assets/src/images/phone.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive">

                    <p class="nav-text">(718)432-6687</p>
                </a>

            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<section class="hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row1">
                <img src="/assets/src/images/logo.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="row row2">
                <h1>A Superior Budget</h1>
                <p class="">HOTEL</p>

                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-text" onclick="window.location.href='/html/booknow.php'">BOOK
                    NOW</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <img src="/assets/src/images/herowoman.png" alt="" class="img-responsive herowoman">
 </section>
```

Comment: a big part of this question revolves around the images used yet the code shown has relative urls for these - the result being that none of the images are available here in StackOverflow which makes it rather tricky to help

Comment: any suggestion how to fix that issue and use images in alternate ways ?

Comment: are these images available on live site? If yes, use the urls for those in the above code

Comment: Have you tried anything with `mix-blend-mode` and/or `background-blend-mode` ? I do not see them set in your css.

Comment: here is an exemple with a few css blend-mode : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508187/how-to-cut-shapes-from-a-layover-or-any-other-html-element/58510867#58510867

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add alpha value to the background color.

Example:

```css
.navbar {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(13px);
}
```

But backdrop filter is not supported in IE and Firefox.
To get around you can use @support and add a fallback property

```
.navbar {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
 padding-top: 1.5rem;
 backdrop-filter: blur(13px);

@supports (
       (-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(13px)) or (backdrop-filter: blur(13px))
     ) {
       background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
       backdrop-filter: blur(13px);
       -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(13px);
     }
}
```